# Excel sum of values if specific date is in specific period and text values are the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables: Table11 and Table1510
In Table11 I have three columns: Date, Numeric value and Text value
In Table1510 I have 4 columns: Startdate, Enddate, Text value and empty column

Now what my formula needs to do is:
Table[1510] empty column =

If Table11[date] = between Table1510[Startdate] + Table1510[enddate]

and Table11[text value] = Table[1510]text value

Then sum all the Table11[numeric value].

I want to autofill this formula down in Table1510 so maybe I'll have to do it with an array formula but I can't make it work.

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
=SOMMEN.ALS('Productiegegevens nieuw.xlsm'!Tabel11[Downtime door technische fout];[@Equipment];'Productiegegevens nieuw.xlsm'!Tabel11[Equipment];[@[Datum uitvoering]];"<="&'Productiegegevens nieuw.xlsm'!Tabel12[Datum];[@[Datum eind uitvoering]];">="& 'Productiegegevens nieuw.xlsm'!Tabel12[Datum])
```

Comment: Are you having trouble finding NL-NL regional language support for SUMIFS ([SOMMEN.ALS](https://support.office.com/nl-nl/article/sommen-als-functie-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)) ?

Comment: Why not build each part separately, then once each part works combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of google translate, I've attempted to determine the problem with your formula. It looks like at least one criteria_range and criteria are out of synch and if the translations are correct then your dates have mismatched `>=` and `<=` operators.

```
Datum uitvoering                 Date of execution (startdate)
Datum eind uitvoering            Date of completion (enddate)
Downtime door technische fout    Downtime due to technical error (numerical value)
Equipment                        Equipment (text value)
```

You will have to add the external workbook name to Table11 but this is what I came up with.

```
=SUMIFS(Tabel11[Downtime door technische fout], Tabel11[Datum], ">="&[@[Datum uitvoering]], Tabel11[Datum], "<="&[@[Datum eind uitvoering]], Tabel11[Equipment], [@Equipment])
```

[image]